# Dividing each corresponding element of two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists in seperate text files and I need to divide each value by the corresponding value in the other list. The following is a smaal bit of the data from both files:

```
738500.0
683000.0
647000.0
623500.0
607500.0

547000
644000
702000
735000
755000
765000
```

I have opened both lists like this:

```
average = open('average2mm.txt','r')
average_content = average.read()
average.close()

difference = open('difference2mm.txt','r')
difference_content = difference.read()
difference.close()
```

I presume I have to use the proper loop to divide both lists but I haven't managed to get it done yet.

Comment: you have them as a text file so when you are doing `average.read()` you are getting back the list as a String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A readable, clean and safe way of doing this would be:

```
with open('average2mm.txt','r') as average, \
     open('difference2mm.txt','r') as difference:

    for avg, diff in zip(average, difference):
        avg, diff = avg.strip(), diff.strip()
        if avg and diff:
            ratio = float(avg) / float(diff)
            print(ratio)
```

If you want to store it in a list:

```
result = []
with open('average2mm.txt','r') as average, \
     open('difference2mm.txt','r') as difference:

    for avg, diff in zip(average, difference):
        avg, diff = avg.strip(), diff.strip()
        if avg and diff:
            ratio = float(avg) / float(diff)
            result.append(ratio)
```

If you want to write to another file, you can either iterate over `result` list and write to file, or:

```
with open('average2mm.txt','r') as average, \
     open('difference2mm.txt','r') as difference, \
     open('ratio.txt', 'w') as ratiofile:

    for avg, diff in zip(average, difference):
        avg, diff = avg.strip(), diff.strip()
        if avg and diff:
            ratio = float(avg) / float(diff)
            print(ratio, file=ratiofile)
            # Or,
            # ratiofile.write(f'{ratio}\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess even easier would be:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.loadtxt('average2mm.txt')/np.loadtxt('difference2mm.txt'))
```

Or you can wrap `(np.loadtxt('average2mm.txt')/np.loadtxt('difference2mm.txt')).tolist()` if you want to have a list.

Answer (score 0):

The zip operation can be used to link one list with the other and the computation part can be handled by the list comprehension and hence providing a shorthand to this particular problem.

Example:

```
test_list1 = [3, 5, 2, 6, 4] 
test_list2 = [7, 3, 4, 1, 5] 
res = [i / j for i, j in zip(test_list1, test_list2)]
# i is the value from list1 and j is the corresponding value from list2
# We divide each by the other and use list comprehension to form an output list. 
print ("The division list is : " + str(res))
```

Output:

```
The division list is : [0.42857142857142855, 1.6666666666666667, 0.5, 6.0, 0.8]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using list comprehension.
Something like this would work:

`res = [i / j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]`